# Store information in RAM for quick access Python

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management

I have 200+ songs in 1 directory that directory has two sub-directories which is full of music and other files I wanted to search for specific music but the search takes so long as it need to search through all the directory and files to find the match each time it happens so I wanted to store the paths to MEMORY so that i can be accessed quickly.
NOTE: I Want to store the path to memory not the music itself because I need to process the path for some other purpose. Any one please help.
Thank You

Comment: How are you searching? If you have only 3 directories most of your paths should in memory from the start.

Comment: Perhaps look into the `@lru_cache` decorator from the `functools` module (Python 3.x). But be careful: it assumes a deterministic result for a given input, so if the file path changes in the future, the program may not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use memcached (https://memcached.org/) This may solve your problem. In your case, PyPI has a python API called python-memcached.